# Problems specifying limits and breaks in scale_y_continuous

Tags: r, ggplot2, yaxis

I'm trying to specify the limits and breaks for primary y-axis and secondary y-axis. Even when I specify the limit and range it is not reflected in the plot.

This is my data:

```
    structure(c(39.571, 36.571, 34, 36.143, 36, 36.571, 38.286, 34.429, 
34.429, 34.714, 33, 30.857, 29.429, 26.429, 25.571, 23.714, 22, 
21.714, 24.286, 29.857, 38, 48.429, 58.714, 70.857, 79, 87, 92, 
99.714, 98.714, 99.571, 101.571, 104.714, 108.857, 112.286, 109, 
109.714, 112.714, 112.143, 114.857, 110.857, 107.143, 107.286, 
108.143, 107.857, 104, 101.286, 99.571, 105.143, 103.143, 103.286, 
98.714, 96, 92.714, 91.286, 84, 83.143, 81.429, 81.286, 82.571, 
82.857, 80.429, 77.857, 75.429, 75.143, 73.286, 74.571, 74.429, 
77, 86.286, 94.857, 96.286, 112.143, 125.286, 137.714, 150.571, 
155, 159.286, 177.714, 175.429, 181.286, 191.143, 181.429, 181.714, 
186.857, 176.857, 174, 158.714, 137.143, 137.429, 131.571, 116.571, 
103.571, 90.857, 81.571, 74.571, 67.143, 54.286, 46.571, 44, 
42.571, 38.286, 37, 34.429, 32.857, 30, 27, 50779.714, 56225.286, 
44278.714, 45877.857, 47517.571, 54886.857, 53798.714, 41703.429, 
34562.286, 46345.429, 42748.571, 37479, 29665, 28040.714, 26415.857, 
29700, 28627.286, 26928.429, 26814, 24773, 22764.143, 22051.571, 
16954.286, 15219.571, 14114.571, 12616, 11874.143, 11393.143, 
11292, 11069.571, 10708.714, 10678.143, 10497.714, 10555.571, 
10725, 10590.286, 11400.714, 11464.571, 11619.571, 11902.143, 
10061.857, 12137.714, 12106.429, 11766.143, 12201.143, 12847.714, 
13207.143, 15696.857, 13885.286, 14280.714, 14310.143, 13927, 
14401.286, 15009.429, 12961.571, 12393.429, 11985.714, 11933.286, 
13572.714, 13333.286, 13202.714, 13256, 13780.714, 13920.429, 
15253.429, 15070.286, 12243.429, 15389.857, 17777.143, 18269.857, 
18231.571, 18068, 17882.286, 20907.571, 18093.286, 15252.286, 
18318.143, 18315.571, 18917.714, 19338.429, 19521.143, 19757, 
23133.286, 20423.429, 20495.143, 20244.857, 20255.429, 17110.571, 
20420.714, 20438, 20552.143, 20564.714, 20735.286, 20657.429, 
20560.857, 20434, 19940.143, 20008.714, 20002.286, 19366.429, 
19262.429, 22270.429, 15850.143, 12969.286, 10271.857, 18361.714, 
17048.571, 16244.571, 18427.143, 18974, 19465.143, 19474.857, 
19754, 17078.286, 19794.571, 18497.571, 18808.571, 18728.714, 
18802.714, 17188.857, 18340, 18294.857, 18484.286, 18384.714, 
18432.143, 18322.429, 18488.714, 18470.857, 17062.143, 18342.143, 
18043.571, 17790.143, 17786.286, 17617.714, 17584.286, 18783.714, 
17439.143, 17673.429, 16980.714, 18735.143, 19837, 18584.857, 
19227.286, 19486.429, 20792.571, 22399.286, 21780.143, 22322.857, 
22465, 23116.714, 24210.286, 23845.286, 24647.143, 24631, 23450.286, 
25279.571, 25612.143, 25757, 25226.714, 20842.429, 19674.571, 
20525.286, 19775, 17391.143, 19574.857, 18560.571, 18557.286, 
18185.714, 17893.857, 17653.286, 17493.714, 14296.429, 18005.857, 
20428.714, 22131.714, 20787.714, 20700, 21965.857, 21809.143, 
18382, 16884.286, 15740.429, 17245.571, 16895.143, 14755.571, 
15246.571, 13380, 14490.429, 14149.429, 13948.571, 13610.571, 
13204, 11294.429, 12238.143, 11733.143, 12460, 11127.143, 11095.857, 
10853.429, 10403.571, 10139.143, 9854, 8584.571, 9430.571, 9142.286, 
8862, 8399, 7955.571, 7721.571, 7414.714, 7153, 7221.857, 26971.286, 
27864.429, 28658.714, 29754.857, 30715.286, 31865.714, 32252.714, 
32683.571, 33662, 34006.714, 34503.143, 34946, 34580.286, 34775, 
35072.571, 34658.429, 34846.857, 34589.571, 34066.286, 33711.286, 
32905.571, 32273.429, 30992.857, 29788.857, 28763.857, 27492.857, 
26285.857, 25187.143, 24251.286, 23697, 22962.286, 22136.286, 
21531.714, 20779.857, 20528.571, 20143.286, 19499, 18362.714, 
17474, 16704.857, 16540.571, 16404.857, 16168.571, 16168.857, 
16856.429, 17032.857, 16557.857, 16044, 15639, 15473.857, 15256.286, 
14733.429, 14705.714, 15225.143, 14382.286, 13501.571, 13174.714, 
12873.857, 13201.571, 13978.429, 14431.714, 14634.571, 15392.857, 
15709.571, 16304.571, 16893.714, 16170.714, 15502, 16666.429, 
17292.143, 17539.571, 17377.714, 16727.286, 16559.714, 16361.857, 
15838.143, 14969.429, 14440.143, 13905, 13590, 13134.571, 12775.857, 
12350.286, 12219.429, 12181.429, 12194, 12425.857, 12469.429, 
12459.429, 12371.143, 12317, 12226.429, 12093.143, 11806.143, 
11705.571, 11798.429, 11902.143, 11958, 11964.286, 12101.571, 
12068, 12279.571, 12233.857, 12245.857, 12163, 12073.714, 20339.571, 
20375.429, 21129.286, 20890.429, 20450.571, 20450.571, 20450.571, 
20074.429, 17407.429, 19043, 18700.571, 18537, 18537, 18537, 
16520.857, 18400.714, 15376, 14907.714, 14019.857, 14019.857, 
14019.857, 12250.286, 12117.286, 11389.286, 10825.857, 10211.143, 
10211.143, 10211.143, 9367.286, 8800, 8672.714, 8363.857, 8062.714, 
8062.714, 8062.714, 7734.429, 6554.857, 6618, 6307.714, 6561.143, 
6561.143, 6561.143, 7079.429, 8554.857, 8741.286, 9337.857, 9523, 
9523, 9523, 9623.571, 9670.143, 9857, 9932.857, 8245, 8245, 8245, 
8594.857, 9085.571, 9704.143, 10473.429, 10473.429, 10473.429, 
10473.429, 11347.286, 12720.286, 10332.286, 13805.571, 17442.143, 
17442.143, 17442.143, 21848.286, 22096.571, 27649.286, 26723.286, 
28829.143, 28829.143, 28829.143, 32095.571, 33360.286, 33747, 
34958.286, 35342.286, 35342.286, 35342.286, 36704.429, 37010.714, 
36826.286, 35475.143, 34794.143, 34794.143, 34794.143, 32774.714, 
31721.714, 30480.429, 29774.857, 28410.143, 28410.143, 28410.143, 
23754.286, 21945.429, 20019.429, 18289.857, 16292.143, 16292.143, 
16292.143, 13885.857, 22754.429, 22347.857, 22418.143, 22573.286, 
22416.714, 22853.857, 22470.857, 22818, 22871.286, 22556.143, 
23892.286, 24462.857, 24733.857, 25362, 25364.571, 25308.714, 
24829.429, 23317.857, 22311.857, 21318.286, 20416.857, 19566.857, 
18321.714, 18124, 17355.571, 16576.571, 16000.857, 15071.857, 
14638, 14945.571, 14656.429, 14284.143, 14507.143, 14462.571, 
15206.571, 15541.714, 15383, 15439.714, 16313.286, 17085, 17938.571, 
18105.571, 18906, 19789.286, 21027.286, 23093.857, 24061.857, 
24875.429, 27381.571, 29258.714, 31881.857, 33894.286, 34410.857, 
35017, 36094, 35581, 36715.714, 39050.571, 40600.857, 43012.429, 
45963.143, 49258.143, 52495.857, 54990.571, 56106.571, 57866.143, 
57403, 59507.857, 59828.571, 59809.857, 58003, 55797.429, 53669.714, 
53100.714, 51342.571, 48675.429, 46338.857, 45101, 43359, 42120.429, 
40573.714, 38350.286, 37239.429, 36016.714, 33821.571, 31923.429, 
29977.286, 28667.857, 27071.286, 25606.714, 24332.286, 23821.429, 
23355.571, 22476.429, 21322.571, 19902.429, 19182.857, 18427.714, 
17780.571, 17142.714, 16265.857, 15238.571, 14666.286, 13950.857, 
13249, 12625.857, 35721.1428, 38597.5428, 40037.2572, 42225.7716, 
43869.8856, 46015.0284, 46602.9144, 48622.9716, 49383.6, 51783.2, 
53799.6572, 56796, 59100.8, 60304.7428, 62707.2, 64033.2572, 
65546.9144, 67076.4572, 68091.8856, 68753.6572, 69353.6572, 70009.6, 
70672.8, 71233.8284, 66688.6284, 67262.9716, 65909.3716, 65532.0572, 
64746.4, 65458.9144, 66555.3144, 72879.3144, 74252.4, 77641.3144, 
79969.7144, 81933.0284, 84010.4572, 85141.2, 85618.1716, 85997.3716, 
86092.9144, 86472.0572, 86389.7716, 85551.0284, 86927.0284, 87409.7716, 
88116.1144, 86699.0856, 86705.9428, 87017.7716, 86334.9716, 85364.7428, 
82740.9716, 73923.6, 75936.6856, 74116.0572, 72719.7716, 72813.4856, 
72999.4856, 75328.3428, 78506.3428, 82702.8, 85723.8284, 86273.3716, 
88253.1428, 89504.6284, 91951.6, 99934.4572, 97745.4284, 98015.4284, 
99739.6, 99323.1428, 97949.0856, 95562.6284, 92629.0856, 89131.3716, 
87081.2572, 83003.6572, 80189.1428, 77486.7428, 75091.3144, 72195.6, 
70445.5428, 67798.1716, 68283.3144, 66546.9144, 64826.8572, 63430.5716, 
62063.7716, 60461.0856, 59365.1428, 58407.6572, 56569.9428, 54798, 
52201.8856, 50341.6, 48165.8284, 46890.6856, 44341.4284, 43251.3144, 
41721.8856, 40702.7428, 38757.2, 37574.6856, 36166.5144, 34118.2856
), .Dim = c(106L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("China", "France", 
"Germany", "Italy", "Spain", "United Kingdom", "US")), index = structure(c(18568, 
18569, 18570, 18571, 18572, 18573, 18574, 18575, 18576, 18577, 
18578, 18579, 18580, 18581, 18582, 18583, 18584, 18585, 18586, 
18587, 18588, 18589, 18590, 18591, 18592, 18593, 18594, 18595, 
18596, 18597, 18598, 18599, 18600, 18601, 18602, 18603, 18604, 
18605, 18606, 18607, 18608, 18609, 18610, 18611, 18612, 18613, 
18614, 18615, 18616, 18617, 18618, 18619, 18620, 18621, 18622, 
18623, 18624, 18625, 18626, 18627, 18628, 18629, 18630, 18631, 
18632, 18633, 18634, 18635, 18636, 18637, 18638, 18639, 18640, 
18641, 18642, 18643, 18644, 18645, 18646, 18647, 18648, 18649, 
18650, 18651, 18652, 18653, 18654, 18655, 18656, 18657, 18658, 
18659, 18660, 18661, 18662, 18663, 18664, 18665, 18666, 18667, 
18668, 18669, 18670, 18671, 18672, 18673), class = c("IDate", 
"Date")), class = "zoo")
```

Ant this is my code (data=n) :

```
ggplot(aes(x = Index, y = Value, group = Series, colour = Series, linetype = Series),
       data = fortify(n, melt = TRUE)) + geom_line(linetype = "solid" , size= 1) + xlab("") + ylab("")+
 scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_number(accuracy =1,breaks = seq(from = 0,to= 80000, by=20000)), expand = c(0,0),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 2.5, labels = scales::label_number(accuracy =1),breaks= seq(from = 0,to = 250000, by=50000)))+ 
  scale_x_date(date_label="%b/%y",date_breaks  ="2 months")+  
            theme_classic()
```

This is the outcome [image]

As you can see in the plot the limits for the primary y-axis goes from 25 000 to 75 000 , instead of going from 0 to 80 000 with 20 000 (increment of sequence). The same thing happen with the secondary y-axis, the limits for the secondary-y axis goes from 40 000 to 240 000 with 40 000(increment of sequence) instead of going from 0 to 250 000 with 50 000(increment of sequence).

Is there another way to specify the breaks and limits so that it is display in my plot? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify the y-axis limits with `coord_cartesian` and modify your breaks in the primary y-axis.

```
df <- n %>% fortify(melt = TRUE) %>% as_tibble()

  df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Index, y = Value, group = Series, colour = Series, linetype = Series)) + 
  geom_line(linetype = "solid" , size= 1) +
  xlab("") + ylab("") +
  scale_y_continuous( breaks = seq(from = 0,to = 100000, by = 20000), ## Modified breaks instructions
                      labels = scales::label_number(accuracy = 1), 
                      sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 2.5, 
                                          labels = scales::label_number(accuracy = 1),
                                          breaks= seq(from = 0,to = 250000, by = 50000))) +
  scale_x_date(date_label="%b/%y",date_breaks  ="2 months") +  
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,100000)) + ## Here is what you need to add
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but the US time-series is still too close to the max value of the secondary y-axis. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand.
Do you want to plot the US line on a different axis range than the rest?
While this is possible with a linear transformation applied only to US values, ggplot2 and the grammar of graphics framework are not your best bet for this kind of plot.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales

Comment: Thank you! your answer was really helpful. Maybe I should plot the US line in another plot.